# fscanf() reading string with spaces in formatted lines

Tags: c, scanf

Using this structure:

```
typedef struct sProduct{
  int code;
  char description[40];
  int price;
};
```

I want to read a txt file with this format:

```
1,Vino Malbec,12
```

where the format is: `code,description,price`. But I'm having problems to read the description when it has a space.

I tried this:

```
fscanf(file,"%d,%[^\n],%d\n",&p.code,&p.description,&p.price);
```

The code is being saved ok, but then in description is being saved `Vino Malbec,12`, when I only want to save `Vino Malbec` because `12` is the price.

Any help?
Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `%[^\n]s` ?

Comment: @darknight I already tried that, and it's the same result

Comment: Try `"%d ,%[^\n,],%d"`

Comment: @chux is saving only the word `Vino` in the description

Comment: Re-wrote - took `' '` out of `"%[^\n, ],"`

Comment: @chux nope. Still having the same issue. To be clear, I'm am writing: `"%d,%[^\n, ],%d\n"`, is that what you meant?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main issue is `"%[^\n],"`.  The `"%[^\n]"` scans in all except the `'\n'`, so `description` scans in the `','`.  Code needs to stop scanning into `description` when a comma is encountered.

With line orientated file data, 1st read 1 line at a time.

```
char buf[100];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, file) == NULL) Handle_EOForIOError();
```

Then scan it.  Use `%39[^,]` to not scan in `','` and limit width to 39 `char`.

```
int cnt = sscanf(buf,"%d , %39[^,],%d", &p.code, p.description, &p.price);
if (cnt != 3) Handle_IllFormattedData();
```

Another nifty trick is: use `" %n"` to record the end of parsing.

```
int n = 0;
sscanf(buf,"%d , %39[^,],%d %n", &p.code, p.description, &p.price, &n);
if (n == 0 || buf[n]) Handle_IllFormattedData_or_ExtraData();
```

---

[Edit]

Simplification: @user3386109

Correction: [@cool-guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3049655/cool-guy) remove &

Comment: @user3386109 True that including `\n` in `"%39[^\n,]"` is really not reeded: coudl be `"%39[^,]"`.  IAC, the check of the return values `fgets()` and `sscanf()` will insure all items exists including the 2nd `','`.

Comment: @Sridhar  Omitting the 39 in `"%39[^,]"` leads to a problem when the `description` input exceeds 39 `char`.  Liberal user of `" "` in a `sscanf()` allows for usually acceptable additional spacing, hence my suggested spaces in the format - though mostly optional.

Answer (score 2):

[@chux](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/28711285/fscanf-reading-string-with-spaces-in-formatted-lines/28711490#28711490) has already posted a good answer on this, but if you need to use `fscanf`, use

```
if(fscanf(file,"%d,%39[^,],%d",&p.code,p.description,&p.price)!=3)
    Handle_Bad_Data();
```

Here, the `fscanf` first scans a number(`%d`) and puts it in `p.code`. Then, it scans a comma(and discards it) and then scans a maximum of 39 characters or until a comma and puts everything in `p.description`. Then, it scans a comma(and discards it) and then, a number(`%d`) and puts it in `p.price`.

Comment: Nice approach to using `fscanf()` directly.  There are subtle differences between `fscanf()` vs. `fgets()/sscanf()`  1) Should file data contain an embedded null character `'\0'`, `fscanf(..."%39[^,]"...)` will consume the `'\0'` and continue. OTOH, so will `fgets()` but its better detected with `sscanf()`. 2) When the input is wrong (bad syntax), the `fgets()/sscanf()` approach is easier to re-sync and continue on than `fscanf()`.  Yet on the `fscanf()` plus side - it is simpler for quick coding.

Comment: I didn't know that! What does an embedded `\0` mean?

Comment: Say a file has the unusual line: "1,abc\0xyz,12\n".  `fscanf( ..."%d,%39[^,],%d"...)` scans 7 `char` into `description` and then appends a terminating null character `'\0'` so it has the contents `"abc"`, a null character , `"xyz"` and a final null character.  Upon printing `description`, only `"abc"` appears.  With `fgets()`, the same `"1,abc\0xyz,12\n".` will be read into a buffer, but `sscanf()` will stop scanning on the first `'\0'` and so only see `"1,abc".` and fail the `sscanf()` parsing.

Comment: Embedded `'\0'` are _not_ common. but they sporadically occur and also are a potential nefarious way for hackers to break code.